# Книга по Java

Tags: java

Нужна книга для сотрудника, который уже знаком с программированием, но в java не знает ничего. Т.е. книга по сути нужна для обучения с нуля, но хочется, чтобы было по меньше воды, чтобы упор был именно на синтаксисе и джава фишках, а не на уже известных определениях и по пять глав о том, что такое компилятор и как установить.

Суть такова, что человек должен освоить java для программирования под desktop, а затем плавно перетечь в андроид программирование. Так что если можете посоветовать сразу цепочку книг для осуществления этого пути, то будем благодарны. Желательно, конечно, книги на русском, но тем не менее, выслушаем все варианты.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Хорстман классный автор!
Советую читать его

Answer (score 2):

[Thinking in Java](http://mindview.net/Books/TIJ4).

Comment: Она же на русском:

"Философия Java" Брюс Эккель.

Мне понравилась. Хорстманн (двухтомник Java 2) тоже очень хорошо, но (IMHO) многовато.

Comment: @avp ну это еще поспорить можно, она же или нет

Comment: @rasmisha, Вы считаете, что в результате перевода получилась *другая* книга ?

Comment: в результате перевода потеряно 400~600 страниц(достаточно много чего, можно просто сравнить какие главы есть в оригинале и нету в переводе), так что думайте, та же эта книга или нет.

Answer (score 2):

Joshua Bloch "Effective Java: Programming Language Guide"

Answer (score 0):

Java. Руководство для начинающих. Герберт Шилдт.

Полный справочник по Java %version%. Герберт Шилдт.

[Android SDK javadoc. RTFM №1](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html)

[Java™ Platform, Standard Edition 7 API Specification. RTFM №2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html)

А вообще представление о том что после прочтения книги по языку программирования, прочитавший вдруг начнет успешно программировать не стоит и выеденного яйца. Вероятность этого примерно такая же как если бы он увидел табличку "биться головой об стену здесь" и в ту же секунду бы ударился.

Кстати программирование на Java под Win 32 x86 и под Android это две большие разницы и плавно перетекать из одного в другое не совсем хорошая идея.